# Can't send a email with python

Tags: python, html-email, smtplib

I'm trying to email a response back the user but I can't get it to work. I'm using email.mime.text and smtplib, libraries. No error is showing in the terminal, but I'm not receiving any email.

Here is the code:

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib

def SendEmail(email, height):
    from_email = 'xxxx@gmail.com'
    from_password = 'xxx'
    to_email = email

subject = 'Height Data'
message = 'Hey there, your height is <strong>%s</strong>' % height

msg = MIMEText(message, 'html')
msg['Subject'] = subject
msg['To'] = to_email
msg['From'] = from_email

gmail = smtplib.gmail.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
gmail.ehlo()
gmail.starttls()
gmail.login(from_email, from_password)
gmail.send_message(msg)
```

Comment: Is your email account configured to block anything but plaintext?

Comment: Looks like you might need to run the `SendEmail()` function.

Comment: Looks like an indentation error to me, the way it is now means you define variables `from_email` and `from_password` inside a function but don't do anything with them there. Once you fix the indentation error (by putting everything inside the function), you need to call that function.

Comment: I get an error with `smtplib` when I run the code. `gmail = smtplib.gmail.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'smtplib' has no attribute 'gmail'. Did you mean: 'email'?`

Comment: @owen i did run the function in another script

Comment: @Schnitte I did run the function in another script.